# Open parent workspace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue with Visual Studio code: before abandoning it I would like to know if there is another way.

Basically I have a folder:

```
D:\work\project1
```

Inside project1 I have a visual studio code workspace file:

```
D:\work\project1\project1.code-workspace
```

**The problem is:** if I try to open a file inside `D:\work\project1` the editor opens without opening the workspace... Each time I open a file I have to reopen the workspace.

[image]

Do I have anyway to open by default the workspace when I edit files inside that folder ?

Comment: try to put the `.code-workspace` file in the directory `D:\work\`. No need to open a folder or workspace to edit a file

Comment: done that: doesn't work